# It is possible to change the Twitter username or screenname via PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm creating a PHP app that basically changes and randomizes everything in a twitter user's profile.

I have managed to change the name, location, description and background colour; but I'm not able to change the screen name. Does anyone know if this is possible? I'm using the twitterOAuth library.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No,

This would leave it open to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: It is possible with cURL.